# Get all product descriptions and then update it

Tags: php, magento2.3, database

i want to get the description of all products in the magento store for all stores. After that i want to change something in the description and update that description in the database. Is this possible? how does the SQL query looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this SQL to select all product descriptions from database:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_text
WHERE
    attribute_id IN (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code LIKE 'description'
                AND entity_type_id IN (SELECT 
                    entity_type_id
                FROM
                    eav_entity_type
                WHERE
                    entity_type_code LIKE 'catalog_product'))
```

Since all product descriptions is saved in `catalog_product_entity_text` table, you can modify above sql to change the description the way you want. If you need to modify using information from other table, e.g. add product name to description, I think you would better go with a php script.

Comment: i do everything with PHP. That query seems to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your SQl Query Look Like

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` SET `value` = 'Change text' WHERE `catalog_product_entity_text`.`value_id` = 25;
```

Table structure

[image]